# jQuery returns wrong width and height in Chrome 18.0.1025.168

Tags: jquery

The following code does not return the correct size for the document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            alert($(document).width());
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="width:100%">
        <div style="width:100%" id="myappClientContainer">DEFAULT HTML</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I set the width of the content of the window to 320, the alert says 426.

The same code reports correctly when using Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421 for example.

Is this a bug with Chrome? Or with jQuery? Or anything else?

I have stumbled on this while trying to set a `div` inside a document to fill the entire size of the document, so maybe this is not the right way to get the dimensions of the entire document?

How do I fix this problem?

---

UPDATE 1:

Following some advice below, I have tried both this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            function sizeme() {
                alert($(document).width());
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="width:100%" onload="sizeme()">
        <div style="width:100%" id="myappClientContainer">DEFAULT HTML</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function sizeme() {
                alert($(document).width());
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="width:100%" onload="sizeme()">
        <div style="width:100%" id="myappClientContainer">DEFAULT HTML</div>

        <!-- YOUR jQuery SCRIPTS here before the '</body>' tag + load from Google (it's faster). -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function($){ // remap '$' to jQuery
                 alert($(document).width());
            })(jQuery);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I still get the wrong size in both of them (**in Chrome 18.0.1025.168**).

I am using jQuery 1.7.2.

Answer (score 2):

You are running that before the complete document has finished loading. Try this:

```
$(function(){
    alert($(document).width());
});
```

Comment: to make sure the complete document has loaded including graphics use:
$(window).load(function () {
  // run code
});

Comment: I am aware of both mentioned methods, I have tried both using `onLoad` and `$(fn())` as I now indicated in UPDATE 1 and neither helps.
Does this code work for you on the browser version I mentioned ?

Comment: Yes, I have the same version (on OSX), and it alerts the document's width as expected. Maybe you are expecting something different, not the document's width? Since the body is 100% width, the alerted number should be the same as the window width (or a little less depending on the browser).

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue on Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m on Windows 8

My laptop display have a horizontal resolution : 1366 px

However Chrome is returning a horizontal resolution (width) higher than the hardware capability of my laptop.

**Using Jquery:**

`$( window ).width()` returns 1483 px

**Using Plain Javascript:**

`window.innerWidth`   returns 1483 px

`document.body.clientWidth` returns 1484 px

(This is also not working)

**Conclusion:**
Since plain javascript returns same wrong value as jquery,
this must not be a bug in Jquery but in Chrome.

**Edit**
Chrome was in a zoom out state in my case.Though my testing tab shown 100% magnification, when I opened another tab, content appeared small, when checked (ctrl +, ctr - on windows) it was zoomed out. After resetting the new tab to 100% (ctrl 0 0n windows), The issue disappeared.

Firefox behaves the same way when zoomed out for me.

Answer (score 0):

"Div" element by itself fills all avalaible horizontal space, so there is no need to define it width.
Also `$(document).width();` is right approach only to GET the width of the document.

Comment: I am aware of that, I have my reasons for wanting to set the width of the div. Specifically it was due to a bug I reported on JQeury 1.7.1 where .width() on an element that was sized to "100%" would report 100 as the size. But any way your response is not related to the problem I described...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- OTHER JS LIBRARY/SCRIPTS -->
</head>     
<body style="width:100%">

<div style="width:100%" id="myappClientContainer">DEFAULT HTML</div>

<!-- YOUR jQuery SCRIPTS here before the '</body>' tag + load from google (it's faster) -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($){ // remap '$' to jQuery
         alert($(document).width());
    })(jQuery);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Save and open in Chrome.

Comment: It does not work. at least not on my version of chrome stated in the Q (18.0.1025.168 m). does it work for you?

Comment: @epeleg Sure! Almost same version. 18.0.1025.168

Comment: hmmm... not sure why I had this "m." listed in my version number (will edit out of the Q). it does not show. So basically we have the same version and different results? did you make sure that it actually alerts the right side and not that it just alerts some number ?

Answer (score 0):

try `document.body.clientWidth`

it works for me