# Media Queries max-width launch at wrong width in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, media-queries

Edit: More research says this is actually related to [jQuery returns wrong width and height in Chrome 18.0.1025.168](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465886/jquery-returns-wrong-witdh-and-height-in-chrome-18-0-1025-168)

I've set up some media queries as well as some javascript on a current wordpress theme project. In general they work fine, but (!) the media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px)
```

Comes in to effect already at 1075px.

```
$(document).width()
1075
$("body").width()
1019.4444427490234
```

This happens in Chrome, but in safari it behaves like it's supposed to. I haven't checked any other browser.

Can you somehow destroy the queries proper "launch-widths" with javacript changing width of elements?

Css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1060px){
.excerpt{
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px){
.hentry{
    height: auto;
}
.thumbnail,.excerpt{
    float: none;
    max-height: none;
}
p{
    font-size: 15px;
}
#site-description{
    display: none;
}
}
```

Latest added javascript before this broke:

```
if($(window).width()<1065 || $(document).width()<1065){
    if($(document).width()>980){
        $(".excerpt").width($(".hentry").width()-515);
    } else{
        $(".excerpt").css("width","");
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I checked my other queries, and they all launch at the wrong width. About 100 too wide each time. So @media (max-width:320px) comes in to effect at about 420px document width. What is it the media queries are checking? Body, document, window or what?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure it has something to do with jQuery?

I had the same problem (media queries triggering at the wrong width) and here the cause was that my zoom-level in Chrome wasn't at 100%. I know, silly me.

Just press cmd+0 or ctr+0 to default to 100%.